# jquery attr combine commands

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm not having luck getting the syntax correct for combining these jquery lines.  Can append be used with attr() or do these just need to be called separately or in the callback? It doesn't have to be append either, it's the only thing writing to that element, I just didn't know any other way of getting text in there.

```
$('#People').append(array.names[9]);
$('#People').attr({
    class: 'blueDescriptorBig'
});
```

Comment: What's `array.names[9]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood correctly, but see below

```
$('#People')
  .append(array.names[9])
  .addClass('blueDescriptorBig'); //Should use addClass instead of .attr for class
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  I'll give you the check when the time is up.

Comment: @rd42 A simple tip is to cache `$('#People')` if it being used in many places in the same function. `var $people = $('#People')` and use $people wherever you want. It may not be a great + for ID based selector but a great improvement for class based selectors or any complex selectors.